# How to run an .exe from linux command prompt

Tags: linux, command-line

I am new to Linux.
I am currently trying to write a command line which should execute a *.exe inside a folder abc.

I have tried

```
% cd abc info.exe
```

But the error says `no such file or directory`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 32):

try:

```
abc/info.exe
```

but if it's really a Windows program, you will need to install "wine", then do:

```
wine abc/info.exe
```

but only some Windows programs will work under wine.

Answer (score 15):

This anwswer is combining other answers in to this question into one.

The info.exe file will either execute under Linux or Windows, but not both.

## Executes Under Windows

If the file is a windows file, it will not run under Linux on it's own.  So if that's the case, you could try running it under a windows emulator (WINE).   If it's not compatible with wine, then you won't be able to execute it under Linux.

Before you can start, you will need to install wine.  The steps you need to install wine will vary on the linux platform you are on.  You can probably google "Ubuntu install wine", if for example, you're installing ubuntu.

Once you have wine installed, then you'd be able to execute these commands.

```
cd abc/
wine info.exe
```

## Execute Under Linux

if you know this file to run under linux, then you'll want to execute these commands:

Change to your abc directory

```
cd abc/
```

Then you'll want to change permissions to allow **a**ll users to e**x**ecute this file (a+x).
you could also allow just the **u**ser to e**x**ecute (u+x)

```
chmod a+x info.exe
```

Launch the program, the ./ tells the command line to look in the current path
for the file to execute (if the 'current' directory isn't in the $PATH environment
variable.

```
./info.exe
```

Comment: *"you could try running it under a windows emulator (WINE)."* WINE does stand for "Wine Is Not an Emulator"...

Comment: @Mefitico was that namesake meant to be ironic or informative?

Comment: My comment was meant to be both a joke a a proposition for an edit. AFAIK Wine basically replaces windows calls for POSIX equivalents, so whoever named it was not ironic, that is WINE is indeed not an emulator.

Answer (score 7):

you can't :) exe is Microsoft only. now if you had a linux executable you could do:

```
cd folder
chmod +x file
./file
```

Comment: This is false in general. Many Windows and DOS EXEs can be run on Linux using emulators such as `wine` or `dosbox`.

Comment: Will a simple C / C++ Program (Using array math and 'printf()') compiled in VS 2017 work in DosBox?

Comment: @Royi probably "yes", but that depends on how simple we're talking. But wine should also do your trick.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux you give the file executable permissions. It isn't the extension that determines whether or not it can be executed (as on windows.)

Assuming you have a valid file that can be executed in Linux, (not a windows/dos file) do this:

```
cd abc
chmod a+x info.exe
./info.exe
```

Note that you need the leading ./ for the shell to find the file in the current directory!

This really belongs on superuser though.

Comment: COuld you explain me. What you are trying to do as Im new

Comment: The first line changes the directory, the second line tells linux it is executable, the third runs the program.

Answer (score 4):

I recently wanted to run some old MSDOS .exe files and I could just use dosbox.  On Ubuntu it was just

`apt-get install dosbox`

then

`dosbox file.exe`

Comment: oh, it's a particular workaround, but is valid for msdos executables.

Answer (score 2):

.exes are generally Windows executables, not linux ones. To run those, use something like WINE.

Otherwise, to run a Linux executable, there are many ways, e.g.:

1. `cd abc; ./info.exe`
2. `./abc/info.exe`
3. `/full/path/to/abc/info.exe`
4. Add "abc" to your PATH, then just run it as a normal command.

Comment: I struggled so much until I found this website and used the 'terminal' tips section at the bottom of the page: https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Wine is a program that you can install, which allows you to run `.exe` files on linux.

`apt-get install wine`

(go to the directory of your file: /cd (ex: Desktop/)
And to open your `.exe` file:

```
wine PROGRAM [AGRUMENTS]
```

If you have any problems with wine, you can do `wine --help`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to run an executable file in Linux:

1. open terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd>: `sudo apt-get update`
2. install Wine: `sudo apt-get install wine`
3. go to the directory in which your .exe file is placed by changing directory: `cd /Desktop`
4. `wine filename.exe`

Hit enter and your .exe file will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

## Executing a Linux executable on Linux

If the executable is a Linux executable, you need to make sure that your shell can find it. Here are some ways how to do that.

But first, make sure it's executable. You can check whether the `x` (executable) flag is set using `ls -l abc/info.exe` and you can set it with `chmod +x abc/info.exe`.

- Run it with relative path, in your example: `abc/info.exe`.
- Run it with absolute path, for example: `/home/username/abc/info.exe` (depends on where it actually is)
- Place the binary in a directory that is part of the `PATH` that is searched by the shell to find binaries. For example, `cp abc/info.exe ~/bin/`. If `~/bin` is part of `PATH`, you can now run `info.exe` without qualifying it.
- Make the directory that contains the binary part of the `PATH`, for example, `export PATH=~/abc:$PATH`. Note that this is for the current shell only, unless you add this line to your `.bashrc` or `.profile`

## Executing a Windows executable on Linux

If the executable is a Windows executable, you need to install `wine`. Then you can run it using `wine abc/info.exe`. If you want to run it like a Linux program, you need to install `wine-binfmt`. Then you can run it the same way as described above for Linux executables.

If you use Ubuntu, install wine like this:

```
sudo apt-get install wine wine-binfmt
```